# How to return object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, redux

**Javascript**

**Object**

```
var initialstate = {
  ddd:{
    aa: '',
    aaa: ''
  }
```

**Syntax Error**

```
return {
  ddd.aa = action.aa,
  ddd.aaa = action.aaa
}
```

**No Error**

```
return {
  aa = action.aa,
  aaa = action.aaa
}
```

How can I return a javascript object with mutiple values which are nested

Comment: Try using colons `:` instead of equals `=`.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are violating JavaScript syntax for objects.

An object literal have the following rules:

- A colon separates property name from value.
- A comma separates each
  name-value pair from the next.
- There should be no comma after the
  last name-value pair.

This is an object literal:

```
var obj = {};
```

You can assign properties and values to them using the following syntax:

```
var obj = {
   myStringProperty: "a string value",
   myNumberProperty: 15,
   myBooleanProperty: false,
   myArrayProperty: [...],
   myFunctionProperty: function (...) {...},
   myComplexProperty: {
       name: "My Name",
       surname: "My Surname",
       family: {
           father: {
               name: "His name",
               age: 60
           }
       }
   }
}
```

As you can see you can have any valid JavaScript primitive type or complex nested objects or arrays or functions as properties. Anything that is valid JavaScript.

For complex names with special characters, for example "my.car" you can have your property in quotation marks, like the following:

```
var obj = {
   "my.car": {
        brand: "Brand",
        model: "Model"
    }
}
```

To fetch the "my.car" object, you don't use the dot notation, but square brackets, just like you would do on a dictionary to fetch the value by the key.
Like this:

`var item = obj["my.car"]; // returns the object defined previously`

Check some simple, 101 tutorials please, like these:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: What if i wanted to do nested reach instead ? So

   `"my.car"` is actually  `car` in the nested `my` object

currently saving it as "my.car" creates a new element

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking here. You want to have some thing like this? `var obj = { my: { car: { brand: "Brand", model: "Model" } }}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the rules.

JSON Syntax Rules

- Data is in name/value pairs (colon separated)
- Data is separated by commas
- Curly braces hold objects
- Square brackets hold arrays

Answer (score 0):

Returning an object works the same as defining a variable to hold an object. Just like you use `var initialstate = {` to initialize a new object the same goes for returning a new object you just replace `var initialstate =` with `return`.

```
return {
  ddd: {
    aa: action.aa,
    aaa: action.aaa
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
var x1 = myJsonString.ddd[0];
var aa=x1.aa;
var aaa=x1.aaa;
```